# How do you say "self improvement"?

Tags: translation

I know that *kaizen* means *improvement* in Japanese, and although it's mainly used for work / business improvement, I understood its not restricted mainly for business.

From a basic Google translate, looks like *Jiko* means *self*. I don't know about Japanese, but the logic of other languages tells me that *Jiko Kaizen* would mean *self improvement*.

Is it true?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, 自己改善 (じこかいぜん in hiragana, *jiko kaizen* in romaji) is a valid literal translation. But if you mean self-improvement suggested by books like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_7_Habits_of_Highly_Effective_People) or [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00KK0PICK), the better-known word for this concept is 自己[啓発](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%95%93%E7%99%BA) (じこけいはつ in hiragana, *jiko keihatsu* in romaji).

Comment: Is 改善 a valid choice to express progress in a skill? For instance, would 私は日本語が改善した be correct? And what about 上達, 進行, or simply 進む?

Comment: @Rightleg 改善 is not wrong, but it may sound like your initial skill was bad. 上達 is much better. 進行/進む makes no sense.

Comment: @Naruto is 自己啓発 (じこけいはつ) the word that would be used to title, say, a section in a bookstore for those kinds of books?

Comment: @squidlydeux It's a word people use to collectively refer to those kinds of books. Here's a [corresponding Wikipedia article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%87%AA%E5%B7%B1%E5%95%93%E7%99%BA%E6%9B%B8). As far as I know, the titles of those books don't usually have 自己啓発 (or similar) explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe more about self-development, but maybe 成長（せいちょう）